# Visual Studio 2012: compile more TypeScript files to one JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript

Is it possible to set a "compiler" option to compile more TypeScript files in one project to one JavaScript file?
The only solution I can find is passing multiple files to the "tsc" manually by hand, but I'd like to use the features of the IDE Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using bundling to do this in ASP.NET. You can use bundling with MVC or Web Forms.

If you are using Web Essentials, you will already be getting both a `.js` and a `.min.js` and bundling is clever enough to use the `.js` files at debug time and the minified versions in production - so you can debug easily but get smaller files in live.

You can read all about [Bundling and Minification on the ASP.NET site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

However, if you want TypeScript to bundle the file (it won't minify it) you just need to use the following flag:

```
tsc --out combined.js app.ts
```

TypeScript will walk the dependencies and sort out the ordering for you so all you need to worry about is minifying the combined file.

Comment: Take care when adding /// <reference/> notations to your TS files, because the compiler will only take them into count when building a bundled JS output if there is NO OTHER CODE before it in the file. I was suffering 2 hours with this before figuring out.

Comment: How is that an answer? Sohnee's solution is not using vs2012